# Salesforce Communities: Safari can't open the page because safari can't establish a secure connecti

Tags: community, ssl, mac-os-x, windows7, safari

**Background**

I have a public Salesforce community page hosted on a **custom domain** with a **RapidSSL (Part of Digicert) SSL certificate**.

I've checked the RapidSSL SSL certificate with [SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html), and everything is set up correctly.

It works for all the different browsers on Windows (10, 8.1, 8, 7, XP)

1. Chrome
2. Firefox
3. Edge
4. IE 11

But it just will not load on **Safari** on Windows (any version)

I get this error:

> Safari can't open the page because Safari can't establish a secure connection

It does work on Safari on Mac OS:

- Mojave
- High Sierra
- Sierra

But does **not** work with Safari on MacOS:

- El Captain
- Yosemite
- Mavericks
- Mountain Lion
- Lion
- Snow Leopard

**Questions**

1. What is causing this `can't establish a secure connection` message?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you check if you have anti virus installed. If yes, try disabling it temporarily.

Comment: @ManishG I am getting this across many computers, as well as the browser testing service called: Browser Stack (https://www.browserstack.com/)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like there is a problem with the certificate.

This SSL Checker will help you diagnose problems with your SSL certificate installation:

- [SSL Shopper: SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html)

Comment: Please do not use answers to post a comment. See [answer] and take the [tour].

Comment: I need 50 reputation points to add a comment @DaveHumm

Comment: you are getting closer to an answer now after the edits, so hopefully you can earn some reputation points.

Comment: The results are good, everything is correct with the SSL certificate

Comment: Does it also fail when viewed via Safari on a macOS machine?

Comment: I've updated with MacOS compatibility